# Extract polygons using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I trying using OpenCV for polygon detection.
After filtering and canny i have:
[image]

How i can take polygon points and fix problems in green circles?
Thanks.

Comment: [`cv::findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29) is a good place to start. Your question will need to be more specific to get good answers.

Comment: Find contours doesn't work because contours in green circles add many errors